# How to make a grid shape using Linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, grid, android-linearlayout

I'm doing a simple calculation application. I'm using the Material Design Button. But there is a gap between the numbers.I tried Grid Layout and the same thing is happening.A gap is created when I switch to the bottom LinearLayout. How can I solve this?

[image]

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/btn_7"
style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
android:text="@string/_7"/>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/btn_8"
style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
android:text="@string/_8"/>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/btn_9"
style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
android:text="@string/_9"/>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/btn_AC"
style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
android:text="@string/ac"/>

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_4"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_4"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_5"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_5"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_6"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_6"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
            app:icon="@drawable/backspace"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconSize="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_1">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_2"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_3"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_enter"
            style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
            app:icon="@drawable/enter"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconSize="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_."
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_."/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_0"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/_0"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_left"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            app:icon="@drawable/left"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconSize="30dp"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_right"
            style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
            app:icon="@drawable/right"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconSize="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="FULL_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3101578796185185/6606345805">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the style.xml I use for the buttons.

```
<style name="NumberButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/numberButton</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/numbertextcolor</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0.5dp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
<item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
```

this code worked for me.DOne